# Scrollbar of Scrollviewer only appears after resizing form or using GridSplitter

Tags: wpf, xaml, scrollbar, scrollviewer, itemscontrol

I have the problem, that the vertical scroll bar doesn't appear after application start.
I fill the *ListPrinterButton* in code behind and set the propertyChanged event. All button are visible in the ItemsControl but the vertical scroll bar only appears, after I resize this area by moving the gridsplitter.

Is there any option to "refresh" the ScrollViewer? I even tried to set VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Visible, but then, the scroll bar is visible, but not editable. Only moving the grid splitter or resizing the form will appear the right opportunity to scroll.

Can you please help?

```
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" x:Name="svDeviceButton" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" PanningMode="Both" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListPrinterButton, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="icPrinter">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Row="1" Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="gsDeviceButton"/>
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why aren't you using a listbox rather than an Itemscontrol? A listbox has a scrollviewer within it.

Comment: Hey Andy, thank you. I tried this, but with the same result. The scroll bar does not appear after application start.

Comment: Nobody any further suggestions? :(